# duplicate entry '0' for key 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I had a table field with datatype as `'smallint'` (primary key) and it was `auto_increment`. It was working fine.

After a long time, I got the error `duplicate entry '32676' for key 1`. So I updated that field from `smallint(6)` to `int(11)`. Now I got the error `duplicate entry '0' for key 1`.

I am using InnoDB engine.

What specifically can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because probably table counter was reset to zero, so next item is added with 0, an existing key!!
You could try to use

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT=32677
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco it works for me now. There was already a record in my table with value of 0 in primary key field. So it was giving me that error.